# Problem using a global variable in an LDAP request

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryservices

My goal is to retrieve the OU names from an LDAP directory and according to each OU name display its sub OU.
All this in C# with a WPF interface.
My OU retrieval function is ok but the problem is with the display function of the sub OUs according to the chosen OU.
I use a global variable and I think the problem comes from there but I don't really know why.
If you know why I'm in :)
I am available for any question.
Thanks

Maxime

There is the code :

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBoxEntite.ItemsSource = OUList;
        afficherOuEntite();
        comboBoxSousEntite.ItemsSource = subOuList;
        afficherOuSousEntite();
    }

    private void btnMinimize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            DragMove();
    }

    public void ComboBoxEntite_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedItemF = "LDAP://myserver.lan/OU=" + comboBoxEntite.SelectedItem.ToString() + ",OU=MPG-Users,DC=myserver,DC=lan";
        TB.Text = selectedItemF;
    }

    public void afficherOuEntite()
    {
        string ldapServer = "LDAP://myserver.lan/OU=MPG-Users,DC=myserver,DC=lan";
        DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(ldapServer);
        DirectorySearcher myDirectorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);
        myDirectorySearcher.Filter = "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)";
        myDirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Name");
        myDirectorySearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;
        SearchResultCollection resultsOuEntite = myDirectorySearcher.FindAll();

        foreach (SearchResult result in resultsOuEntite)
        {
            string ouName = result.Properties["Name"][0].ToString();
            OUList.Add(ouName);
        }
    }

    public void afficherOuSousEntite()
    {
        DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(selectedItemF);
        DirectorySearcher myDirectorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);
        myDirectorySearcher.Filter = "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)";
        myDirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Name");
        myDirectorySearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;
        SearchResultCollection resultsOuSousEntite = myDirectorySearcher.FindAll();

        foreach (SearchResult result in resultsOuSousEntite)
        {
            string ouName = result.Properties["Name"][0].ToString();
            subOuList.Add(ouName);
        }
    }
    public List<string> OUList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> subOuList = new List<string>();

    public static string selectedItemF;
}
}
```

The result I have concerning the sub-OR is an empty result, as if the search was not based on anything

Comment: Your `selectedItemF` variable should be the LDAP path of the OU. For example, `LDAP://myserver.lan/OU=SubOU,OU=MPG-Users,DC=myserver,DC=lan` Is it?

Comment: Yes is it, on the fontion ComboBoxEntite_SelectionChanged we can see i put the path on the variable. I dont know why my DirectoryEntry can't read my global variable....

Comment: So `afficherOuSousEntite()` should run after `ComboBoxEntite_SelectionChanged`? How does that happen? Also, how and where is `selectedItemF` declared?